# Iterating over linked list in C

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

I have a linked list that contains two "strings", one for searching and one for replacing. I also have a text file that I'm supposed to open and read line by line then see if the words exist in the "dictionary" (the linked list) if it does, I have to replace it with the word's definition. Then write the changed text into a new text file, so I thought I should use a buffer when reading.

The problem is, I don't know how to iterate over the linked list. So far I have two words in it but it only searches for the first one in the loop:

```c
char *textLine = NULL;
size_t textlen = 0;
ssize_t readText;
struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
n = head;
char buffer[MAX_L];

while ((readText = getline(&textLine, &textlen, t)) != -1) {

    char *t = strtok(textLine, " ");

    while (t != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(t,n->word) == 0) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }
        n = head;
        t = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

`head` is `NULL`, I guess that's why it only searches for the first word I just don't really know how should I iterate over both the lines and the linked list.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some sort of `n = n->next;` assignment or the like within the inner `while` loop. Instead of just doing `n = head;`.

Answer (score 4):

How, specifically, to iterate over a linked list depends, to some extent, on its interface.

Not having the interface to the particular implementation you are using available, the question is difficult to answer; but typically; a linked list looks something like this:

```
typedef struct list_node ListNode;

struct list_node {
  void *payload;
  ListNode *next;
}
```

Iterating is usually (always?) done by following the `next` pointer, so long as it is not `NULL`; like so:

```
void iterate (ListNode *head) {
  while (head) {
    if (interested_in_payload(head->payload)) {
      // do stuff
    }

    head = head->next;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
n = head;
```

looks very scary. It's almost never correct to first allocate some memory, then immediately overwrite the pointer.

Perhaps you meant

```
head = n;
```

?

Comment: Never is a dangerous word. Personally, I'd probably go with "not" for this case, and "very rarely" for the more general concept. (Weird things happen in embedded programming.)

Comment: @WillihamTotland Hm ... yeah, okay, why not, I made it "almost never". :)